# Java server software not recieving connections when compiled to executable Jar

Tags: java, netbeans, tcp, javafx, executable-jar

I have written code for a tcp (SSL) server which receives client connections and distributes data to the clients. the server GUI is based on JavaFX. When i run the server software from within Net Beans or Eclipse it works fine, receives client connections and sends and receives data. But when i compile the code into an executable Jar the server does not receive connections and client code throws: Connection refused exception.

I have tried pinging the server and it seems the server does not listen to the specific port when it is run from the executable Jar but DOES when run from within the IDE.

to be honest , I have no idea what could be causing this behavior. would appreciate any insights , suggestions or leads into how to fix this issue. I dont think the specific code is relevant but if somone thinks it is i will post the server code.

Comment: may be javaFX crates some kind of sandbox and you have to tell it to let socket connections in? http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/1.3/tutorials/Create-Secure-JavaFX-App/index.html

Comment: interesting, but i doubt that is the case since in does work when run from an IDE. why would the same code running through an IDE allow something and then not allow it when the application is deployed!? I really hope this is not the case, if so , would be pretty un-smart. you could never tell how your application would work. looking into it though, thanks.

Comment: If the server fails to listen at the port either your code is never getting there or you are ignoring the resulting exception.

Comment: netbeans can be in firewall's whitelist while standalone java don't, you may want to check it

Comment: Turned the firewall off in order to eliminate that. still nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out the problem was that the relevant keystores were not being loaded right. They were being loaded as FileInputStreams which will not work when embedded inside a Jar file.
I reverted them to being loaded as InputStreams , which work just as well with the SSL context and everything seems to be working right now.

Thanks a bunch for all the suggestions they defiantly helped me eliminate things along the way.

Comment: You must have suppressed every exception in sight for that not to be immediately apparent.